# How to download image using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hi I have picture on a page which has to be downloaded and then be used to import to another site.

whis is what the site looks

[image]

I want to download this using xpath and the xpath is `//*[@id="word-img"]/img`.

code of the picture looks like this

```
    <div id="word-img" style="width: 600px; height: 200px; margin-bottom: 20px; background: white;"><img src="https://10fastfingers.com/anticheat/generate_word_picture?rand=8644839612" alt=""></div>

<img src="https://10fastfingers.com/anticheat/generate_word_picture?rand=8644839612" alt="">
```

Comment: did my answer worked for you?

Comment: yes I am thankful for your answer

Comment: Great, you are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do that.
1.

```
import urllib

# get the image source
img = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="word-img"]/img')
src = img.get_attribute('src')

# download the image
urllib.urlretrieve(src, "my_image.png")
```

2. 

```
with open('my_picture.png', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="word-img"]/img').screenshot_as_png)
```

Comment: Some imgages are dynamically generated and every request will return a different file, is there anyway to get the exact image shown in the browser with selenium?